# Why isn't "--force-recreate" rebuilding my docker mysql image?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, recreate

I had created a docker MySql 5.7 image, and then wanted to change a couple of names.  My docker-compose.yml file ended up like so

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'maps_data'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'myuser'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : < MySQL Port running inside container>
      - '3406:3306'
    expose:
      # Opens port 3406 on the container
      - '3406'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
# Names our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
```

I wanted to rebuild my image from scratch and thought "docker-compose up -d --force-recreate" was the way to go ...

```
localhost:maps davea$ docker-compose down
Stopping maps_db_1 ... done
Removing maps_db_1 ... done
Removing network maps_default
localhost:maps davea$ 
localhost:maps davea$ docker-compose up -d --force-recreate
Creating network "maps_default" with the default driver
Creating maps_db_1 ... done
maps_db_1 is up-to-date
Attaching to maps_db_1
db_1  | 2020-01-28 23:16:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.29-1debian9 started.
db_1  | 2020-01-28 23:16:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db_1  | 2020-01-28 23:16:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.7.29-1debian9 started.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.051193Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.052820Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.29) starting as process 1 ...
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.056843Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.056912Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.056928Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.056944Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.056959Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.056975Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.057616Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.057757Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.059523Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.070356Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.073066Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.084799Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.097204Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.097391Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.134350Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.135692Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.135748Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.136582Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.192038Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.29 started; log sequence number 12442166
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.192864Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.193111Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.194918Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200128 23:16:20
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.198841Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.198900Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of SSL certificates as certificate files are present in data directory.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.199651Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.199712Z 0 [Note] Skipping generation of RSA key pair as key files are present in data directory.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.200248Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.200400Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.200413Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.200633Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.204771Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.217005Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1  | 2020-01-28T23:16:20.217626Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1  | Version: '5.7.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

However, when I login as the root user, I don't see my database "maps_data" there.  I see the old "db" database before I made my changes though ...

```
localhost:maps davea$ mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 --port=3406 -p 
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.29 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases
    -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| db                 |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

What's the proper way to completely start from scratch and rebuild my docker MySql image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tell docker-compose to remove the image by passing in the `--rmi` flag to down:

`docker-compose down --rmi all`

This tells compose to stop and remove all containers, networks, and remove all images used by any service in your docker-compose file. Additionally, you can pass `--volumes` to remove all named volumes (`my-db` in your case). However, this will cause the named volumes in your docker-compose file to be removed, and you'd lose that data. Ensure this is what you want.

Then, to re-run the application with the new images, use the `--build` option with docker-compose up to build the images before starting the containers.

`docker-compose up -d --build`

See the docker-compose reference for [up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) and [down](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) for further options.

Answer (score 2):

docker-compose's --force-recreate will delete the container and build a new container from the image name/Id provided (in your case mysql:5.7). I would imagine that is happening as it should. You can tell if you look at the container Ids before and after the docker-compose up ... --force-recreate. If the Ids of the container change, then docker-compose did indeed create a new container from the mysql:5.7 image.

If you look at the docker-compose yaml file, you can see it is going to use a docker volume named 'my-db' mounted at /var/lib/mysql inside the container. Docker volumes are persistent (which is one of their main use cases) so when the new container is created it mounts the 'my-db' volume back to /var/lib/mysql, which persists your data to the new container.

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

> Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers.

What you want to do if you want to truly start from a clean slate is to issue a `docker-compose down` (which will delete the container) and ensure the 'my-db' volume is also removed (using docker volume ls). If the volume is still there, remove the volume with `docker volume rm my-db`. After that, issue a `docker-compose up -d` and it will build a new volume (that will be empty) and the new container will see no files in /var/lib/mysql.